# PWM an AC pump using MOSFET

Tags: arduino, mosfet, ac, pwm

I'm currently stuck on my project as I'm not sure what to do with PWMing my pump as I want to adjust the pressure.

I will be using an Arduino for PWM. The pump  is 60W @ 230V 50Hz mains and is a vibratory pump, it has a built in diode so it only sees half of AC signal.

My question is would this circuit work? Do I need to add additional passive components? I think I do, but I don't know what or where should I add them.

[image: current circuit]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Gate drive varies vastly with mains cycle. Adding a low voltage DC supply to drive R2, Ra ... would help. This could be driven from rectified mains with a series resistor and capacitor  and zener diode - but a small plug pack with floating output would be easier. But - see my answer re series resistor trial and other methods. Where are you located? What access to parts?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comments. I forgot to mention I'm doing this 'upgrade' for a Nespresso machine, so I would like to mainly modify the circuitry rather than the machine. I'm located in UK, access to parts is no problem.

Comment: right, so that AC source is lowVoltage and power limited - I was wondering why you were shorting out the DC of the rectifier, but it is more to permit powerflow

Answer (score 1):

The circuit is potentially OKish BUT there is no certainty that it will work.

If PWM frequency is >> mains frequency then You are effectively reducing driving amplitude.
Adding series resistors in the AC line will give you some indication of how effective this will be.

An alternative would be to miss out some half cycles.
This would be annoying acoustically and pump MAY have some electromechanical resonance which requires a few cycles to get up to pressure.

If you "subcycled" it and fed a reservoir of suitable size so that you achieved smoothed average flow it would achieve pressure reduction.

An alternative which would work is to operate the pump continually into a reservoir and then modulate a bleed valve which vented pressure to ambient. By changing the bleed rate you would change available pressure. You can buy small solenoid valves intended for a range of purposes and fabrication of something yourself should be achievable. If "all else fails" the filling solenoids used in most washing machines could be repurposed for this use. Add a suitably small bleed orifice on the exit side, or feed them with a semi clamped flexible tube or ... . These valves are usually operated on/off but may be amenable to partial opening using DC feed. Some will have AC mains coils but others will be low voltage DC powered. Don't forget a reverse diode across the solenoid coil.

---

ADDED:

Q: > so would a SSR with random turn on mode be okay instead of the MOSFET?

A: Probably not.
As Phil said and as I suggested, the issue of working is more with the pump than the driving method. Read his comments on pump operation and mine re trying a series resistor.
**BUT** an SSR will probably be less effective than your MOSFET cct because they are almost always TRIAC based and once on will stay on for the rest of a half cycle. If you fire it randomly with trigger rate >> Fmains you will get ~= 100% on and if you fire it randomly at around 2Fmains (half cycle rate) you'll get about 50% on mean period but with a spread of periods  - which your pump may or may not like.Fire randomly at < half cycle rate and you'll get 0 to 1 1/2 cycle on each firing.

An easy test to start with is to get several power resistors of various values (or a suitable length of Nichrome or similar wire)(taking care not to electrocute yourself) and try adding these in series with the pump and see what effect it has.  This is not a direct substitute for your PWM'd FET but should give an idea of how the pump responds.

Comment: so would a SSR with random turn on mode be okay instead of the MOSFET

Comment: @zhangxu92 As Phil said and as I suggested, the issue of working is more with the pump than the driving method. Read his comments on pump operation and mine re trying a series resistor. | **BUT** an SSR will probably be less effective than your MOSFET cct because they are almost always TRIAC based and once on will stay on for the rest of a half cycle. If you fie it randomly with trigger rate >> Fmains you will get ~= 100% on and if you fire it randomly at around 2Fmains (half cycle rate) you'll get about 50% on mean period but with a spread of periods  - which your pump may or may not like.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will work, but the reason isn't electrical, it's mechanical.

The pump in a Nespresso machine is a kind of positive displacement pump. These kinds of pumps are better suited than centrifugal pumps to producing the high pressure, low volume fluid flow needed to make espresso.

Judging by the loud 60 Hz (or 50 Hz, in some parts of the world) groan and ample vibration my Nespresso machine makes, I bet it's a [vibratory piston pump](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=we9IZJ5tQFs). There is a piston that fits tightly inside a cylinder, and there is an inlet and outlet connected to this cylinder through check valves. When the input diode is reverse biased, a spring pushes the piston back, drawing in water through the inlet. When the AC cycle reverses polarity, the diode becomes forward-biased, and a solenoid is energized which pushes the piston to drive water out the outlet at high pressure. Then the AC cycle reverses polarity again and the cycle repeats.

So with each cycle, this pump delivers some volume of fluid, that volume being determined by the displacement of the piston. The frequency of the cycles is determined by your AC frequency.

Consequently, the volume of water per unit time that this pump delivers is roughly constant. The water will be delivered at whatever pressure is required, depending on the fluid resistance the pump must work against. Unless that resistance is too high, then the motor will stall, break, or burst a safety seal.

Normally we make hydraulic analogies to electrical systems, but here I'll do the inverse. This pump is a current source: the flow is constant and the pressure is determined by the resistance it has to work against to achieve that flow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZHECn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

PWMing the motor will just make it unable to work against higher resistances, which require a higher force to move the piston. This does not sound like what you want.

If your goal is to vary the pressure of the pump's output, then you probably want a way to control the resistance of the output (or find a different pump). To reduce the resistance you could add a bypass which diverts some of the fluid output to the input. This will in turn reduce the pressure of the output.

Alternately, you could reduce the pump flow by skipping cycles. Normally, the pump delivers its volume of fluid with each AC cycle. You might reduce this by energizing the piston every other cycle. The issue you will have here is that the output pressure will fluctuate in the long interval between strokes. However, this is already an issue with the Nespresso pump, and solving it probably [involves an entirely different kind of pump](https://www.seattlecoffeegear.com/learn/videos-home/ask-the-experts/compare-rotary-v-vibratory-pumps).

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn off the current instantly because off the inductance of your motor. The circuit, as draw, will cause huge spikes, maybe up to max. reverse voltage of your diodes, catastrophic failure pending.

A resistor (a few Ohms) between the AC terminals of your rectifier, would provide a path for the current to continue. This will limit the lower bound of your PWM, but I suspect that you are not interested in 0%-100% but rather 50%-100% PWM operations. A small inductor between the + terminal of the rectifier and the FET will limit the current spike as you turn on the FET, but don't forget to add a flyback diode.